# Ember: How do I make vendor.css to be generated inside assets/css instead of assets?

Tags: ember.js

I have tried doing `app.import('bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', {destDir: 'css'});` without any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ember assets would be

```
/assets/application-name.js
/assets/application-name.css
```

and if you import

```
/assets/vendor.js
/assets/vendor.css
```

To change these paths, specify the `outputPaths` config option in `ember-cli-build.js`. The default setting is shown here:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      html: 'index.html',
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/application-name.css'
      },
      js: '/assets/application-name.js'
    },
    vendor: {
      css: '/assets/vendor.css',
      js: '/assets/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```

You may edit any of these output paths, but make sure to update your `app.outputPaths.app.html`, default it is `index.html`, and `tests/index.html`.

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      js: '/assets/main.js'
    }
  }
});
```

The `outputPaths.app.css` option uses a key value relationship. The key is the input file and the value is the output location. Note that we do not include the extension for the input path, because each preprocessor has a different extension.

When using CSS preprocessing, only the `app/styles/app.scss` (or `.less` etc) is compiled. If you need to process multiple files, you must add another key:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    app: {
      css: {
        'app': '/assets/application-name.css',
        'themes/alpha': '/assets/themes/alpha.css'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Remember you must change your css folders as well,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/yournewurl/vendor.css">
```

Comment: This worked. I have one prob though. I'm getting 'Cannot GET /assets/css/vendor.css'. why is that?

Comment: you need to change vendor.css url in index.html, added to the my note, under index.html in /app